# Can't SSH to Ubuntu PC (host) over ethernet after unplugging and replugging ethernet cable

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ethernet, port

The issue is that on fresh boot I can easily `ssh` to the target Ubuntu 16.04 server pc over ethernet (direct cable link between the two PC) from a PC running Ubuntu 18.04. After exiting safely with the command `exit`, I unplug the ethernet cable and upon re-plugging, I can no longer `ssh` or `ping` to the target Ubuntu 16.04 server PC. I checked the status of port via `nmap` and I get:

```
admin@MTL01WI-200589:~$ nmap -p22 192.168.131.1 -Pn

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-08-05 22:47 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.131.1
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

Not sure why the state changes from "open" to "filtered" and what can I do to `ssh` again to the host PC. I haven't been able to find a relevant solution anywhere. The ufw status is inactive.

Trying to ssh gives:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.131.1 port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: On which machine did you run the nmap? The SSH server or the other computer? And are you sure that the link does come back online on BOTH sides of the connection after reconnect. Auto-negotiate is NOT guaranteed to work properly in point2point connections and may work differently on boot than on disconnect/reconnect.

Comment: I ran nmap on 18.04 i.e. the "other computer". I am not sure what you mean by "...link does come back online on BOTH sides..." The only thing I am aware of is that after cable reconnect, I cannot SSH to the server 16.04. I need to do a reboot on the server 16.04 side in order to bring up the link again. 
I have a found a work around to the reboot for now. I can run "ifdown eth0" and then do a networking restart by running "/etc/init.d/networking restart" in order to be able to SSH again. Would definitely appreciate a more sophisticated routine.